# Measure job execution time in flink

Tags: apache-flink

Is there any way to measure job execution time in Apache Flink when submitting the job to flink using command line?

PS. I want the flink API to give me the time rather than measuring it myself in bash by noting the start and end times

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `ExecutionEnvironment.execute()` method returns a `JobExecutionResult` object containing the job runtime.

You could for example do something like this:

```java
// execute program
JobExecutionResult result = env.execute("My Flink Job");
System.out.println("The job took " + result.getNetRuntime(TimeUnit.SECONDS) + " to execute");
```

Comment: how do I stop the flink program when one event has been detected?

Comment: you could throw an exception. Or you use cancel the job via the REST Api once you've seen the event.

Comment: can you please give me some example, or refer me to some example